# Internet Explorer shows raw HTML text when using @ResponseBody

Tags: internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I am generating response content using @ResponseBody. Internet explorer displays this as raw HTML. However, when I do a F5 refresh then the HTML is displayed correctly.

I do not experience this problem with Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Are you setting content-type to text/html?

Answer (score 1):

I thought I was setting the content-type to text/html. I downloaded Fiddler to enable me to view the request and response headers and the content-type was image/gif.

I had tried both:

```
httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

and

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

Neither of these seemed to work. So I was unable to explain why they weren't being sent to the client.

I ended up implementing the response using HttpEntity instead. This [section on HttpEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-httpentity) does say that it gives access to the headers.

```
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
return new ResponseEntity<String>(content, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```